# Need help fixing Incorrect code to ask the user user if they would like to print the numbers in ascending or descending order

Tags: python

> I just need someone to correct my code to do exactly the following
> instructions:
>
> Create a Python program that prints the numbers from 1 to 10. The
> program will ask the user if they would like to print the numbers in
> ascending or descending order.
>
> If printing the numbers in ascending (1 to 10) order, you must use a
> while loop in the printing of the numbers. If printing the numbers in
> descending (10 to 1) order, you must use a for (with the range
> function) loop in the printing of the numbers.

```
My Code:

input("Would you like to print the numbers in ascending or descending order?: ")
if input ("ascending"):
 print(num)
elif input ("descending"):
    print (range)

num = 1
while num < 11:
    print(num)
    num = num + 1
    
for range in [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]:
    print(range)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the *return value* of the input prompt:

```
answer = input("ascending or descending? ")
if answer == "ascending":
    ...
elif answer == "descending":
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the while loop after checking if ascending & move the for loop bellow checking if descending. Though, your for loop could be written in better way. I am skipping that part.

```
if input ("ascending"):
    # move your while loop code here
elif input ("descending"):
    # move your for loop code here
```

Comment: The code helps but my output is incorrect. When I type for example the word 'ascending' and hit enter, the output displays the word 'ascending' and that's it. I want it to display my numbers in the ascending order after I type ascending in the output box. how would I fix this?